# Haskell SQLite3 query all

Tags: sqlite, haskell

Would like to determine the size of a table (length) to avoid a user entering an incremental ID that already exists (Note: left all Haskell books to get my feet wet). Got a table with `id, task, date_in, date_out` and need to count the number id's. Using this function:

```
checkUniqueID = do
  conn <- open "taglist.db"
  len <- query conn "SELECT * FROM task;" (Only xxx) :: IO [id]
  let showLength = length $ len
  print showLength
  close conn
  return ()
```

However: omitting the '`Only`' will result in ghci mentioning too few arguments, but I really cannot figure out what to put at xxx. Too bad all Haskell doc is so fragmented, since it is such a cool language. 
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not terribly familiar with these libraries. I check the docs
of [`Database.PostgreSQL.Simple`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#t:ToRow)
and found out that, if you don't have arguments to your query, you can use `query_` and omit the argument tuple. The examples at the very beginning of the docs are quite helpful.

That being said, your approach looks wrong. You are pulling the whole table from the DB only to count the entries. This is a waste: you should instead use something like `select count(*) from ..` so that you query for the length only.

This might work: (again, I've never used that library)

```
[Only len] <- query_ conn "select count(*) from task" :: IO [Only Int]
```

Comment: Hi @Chi with a little change it works. Thanks so much to get me on track again. Library is new for me too and on pulling in the entire table like I did, SQLite throws an error anyway. Maybe if others run into this 'problem' and read your reply, here's the modified code that works:
  `conn <- open "taglist.db"\n
  len <- query_ conn "SELECT (id) FROM task" :: IO [Only Int]
  let showLength = Data.List.length $ len
  print showLength
  close conn
  return ()`

Comment: @Madderote If you have a completely working code, you can post it answering your own question. StackOverflow's policy encourage self-answers, when they can be useful to others.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will do with future issues, which I will encounter for sure ;-)